# AlertDialog in method?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to press button1 and have "one text" sent to one textView and to press button2 and have "another text" sent to another textview.

I want to use the same method (displayAlert),
but I think I'm missing something.

Or is it not possible this way? Mabe there is a better way.

Here is my code:

```
public class LoggFactActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

final Context context = this;
private String hintText;
private TextView tv;
private TextView editTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logg_fact);


    //First button
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fact_btn_1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final TextView loggTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayAlert("Reg.number", loggTextView);
        }
    });

    //Second button
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fact_btn_2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final TextView loggTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_2);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayAlert("Modell", loggTextView);
        }
    });
}

public void displayAlert(String hintText, final TextView tv){

    //set the text in alertdialog text view
    editTextview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ad_logg_fact);
    editTextview.setHint(hintText);

    // get the logg_fact_alert_dialog view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View alertDialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.logg_fact_alert_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // set logg_fact_alert_dialog to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(alertDialogView);

    final EditText userInput = alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ad_logg_fact);

    //set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("SAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            //get user input and set to result edit text
            tv.setText(userInput.getText());
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    //create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    //Show it
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, also why you are casting a edit text to textview editTextview

Comment: editTextview is just a name. I will change it if i get the code to work.

Comment: And the casting was wrong, I have changed it. But the code is not working.    I want to be able to put in and change text. It can/will be multiple rows with different alterable text. And I want to be able to change one row at time. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should find EditText and set hint to it after inflating content view of dialog.

Remove this lines

```
//set the text in alertdialog text view
editTextview = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ad_logg_fact);
editTextview.setHint(hintText);
```

Add this

```
userInput.setHint(hintText);
```

below line

```
 final EditText userInput = alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ad_logg_fact);
```

Comment: You're wellcome :) One more thing, checkout [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library. It's the material dialogs library for android. It contains a lots of useful functionalities and backward compatibility for older versions of android